# Making the only first label of a list (itemize) empty (on preamble)

Tags: enumerate, itemize, enumitem

I'm currently using

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item[]
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}
```

each time I create a list to make sure that the label of the first item is empty. This is cumbersome and might be problematic if I ever decide to change the styling. Is there a way to set it in default in the preamble?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this behaviour if you define your own `enumerate`-style with a weird counter output.

`\@firstempty` defines a counter format that prints nothing if the counter is 0 and `\labelitem<listdepth>` otherwise. So its output is suppressed if the counter is zero, otherwise it is the same as the label you get from `itemize` otherwise. We then make this counter format known to `enumitem` and define our new environment `feitemize` based on that counter format.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\def\firstempty#1{\expandafter\@firstempty\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@firstempty#1{\ifcase#1\else\csname labelitem\romannumeral\the\@listdepth\endcsname\fi}
\makeatother
\AddEnumerateCounter*{\firstempty}{\@firstempty}{1}
\newlist{feitemize}{enumerate}{5}
\setlist[feitemize]{label=\firstempty*,start=0}

\begin{document}
\texttt{feitemize}:
\begin{feitemize}
  \item Hallo
  \item Hello
  \item Hoi
\end{feitemize}

For comparison \texttt{itemize} with empty first label:
\begin{itemize}
  \item[] Hallo
  \item Hello
  \item Hoi
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution with `etoolbox` and `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass[x11names]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newbool{firstitem}

\setlist[itemize,1]{label=\ifbool{firstitem}{\global\boolfalse{firstitem}}{\color{Red3}\textbullet}, before=\booltrue{firstitem}}%\

\begin{document}

Some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text.
\begin{itemize}
  \item First 
  \item Second
\item Third
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]